# Open Group Base Specifications, Single UNIX Specification and POSIX

Tags: posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What differences are between POSIX and Single UNIX Specification?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14368/what-differences-are-between-posix-and-single-unix-specification)

Having asked about [the relation between POSIX and Single UNIX Specification](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14368/what-differences-are-between-posix-and-single-unix-specification), I was now wondering what relation are between [the Open Group Base Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html), Single UNIX Specification and POSIX?

Thanks and regards!