# Is Linux considered XSI compliant or largely so?

Tags: linux, posix, standard

From APUE

> The Single UNIX Speciﬁcation, a superset of the POSIX.1 standard,
>   speciﬁes additional interfaces that extend the functionality provided
>   by the POSIX.1 speciﬁcation. POSIX.1 is equivalent to the Base
>   Speciﬁcations portion of the Single UNIX Speciﬁcation.
>
> The X/Open System Interfaces (XSI) option in POSIX.1 describes
>   optional interfaces and  deﬁnes  which  optional  portions  of 
>   POSIX.1  must  be  supported  for  an implementation  to  be  deemed
>   XSI  conforming. These  include  ﬁle  synchronization, thread stack
>   address and size attributes, thread process-shared synchronization,
>   and the
>   _XOPEN_UNIX symbolic constant (marked ‘‘SUS mandatory’’ in Figure 2.5).  Only XSI-conforming implementations can be called UNIX systems.

Is it correct that SUS consists exactly of POSIX and XSI?

Is it correct that Linux (or Ubuntu, Debian in particular) is POSIX compliant?

Is Linux (or Ubuntu, Debian in particular) considered XSI compliant or largely so?
I ask this because then I will know whether the parts in APUE labelled for XSI apply to Linux  (or Ubuntu, Debian in particular).

I am mainly interested in API, so does that mean Linux kernel suffices?

Comment: Re your first question, see [Is Posix a subset of Single UNIX Specification?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419307/86440)

Comment: Re the second question, see [Why isn't GNU/Linux SUS v3+ compliant?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6171).

Comment: @Kusalananda: Your pointer points to a wrong answer: Linux had an offer to get a full (assisted by Andrew Josey) certificaton for one Dollar but after a while told the OpenGroup that they are not willing to become fully compliant.

Comment: @schily was that for Linux in general (and if so, how was it defined), or a specific distribution? (Or perhaps several distributions...)

Comment: AFAIR, this was at the end mainly caused by the people behind the GNU tools.

Comment: The correct place for a right answer to that question is _as an answer over there_, not in question comments here.

Comment: This question is overly broad, as it is _four questions in one_.  As others have pointed out, we already have questions and answers dealing with the relationships between the documents and options, and at least one of the four questions here is unnecessary.

Comment: POSIX/SUS is dead. Nobody cares about it anymore. Linux is the new standard, because that is what servers use. The paid standard never was truly implemented by anyone. There were always cases where each platform (even when "certified", that is just the sales label that you can buy to appear more important than you are. Like the Intel inside sticker on many laptops...) would deviate from the spec.

Comment: In particular, it requires a number of ancient dead APIs and tools, such as pax to be installed that nobody uses anymore. Going for full POSIX support is useless. And really: *who cares*? Does your car satisfy the horse carriage safety requirements of 1876?

Answer (score 5):

Linux is not fully POSIX compliant. There are e.g. system calls that behave differently (sorry I currently do not remember what the differences are exactly; I'll describe them here when I remember again).

One problem is e.g. that Linux does not include a correct `waitid()` system call (that delivers all 32 bits from the `exit()` parameter) and the Linux kernel people do not like to fix this. ([`waitid()` has existed since AT&T System V Release 4.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224452/5132).)

Some of the `XSI` features are implemented in Linux but not all of them.

`bash` (the way it is compiled for Linux distros) comes e.g. with a non `XSI` compliant `echo` builtin, `dash` does not support `multi byte chars` which is required by `XSI`. This happened after some time of POSIX adoptions after Linux got the offer to get an assisted certification for one Dollar.

If you like to get a correct overview, you might be interested to search the net for the final paper of POSIX non-compliances in Linux from Andrew Josey that has been written after the Linux people told the Opengroup that they are no longer interested in becomming POSIX compliant.

See: http://www.opengroup.org/personal/ajosey/tr20-08-2005.txt

BTW: There are rumors that Red Hat recently received a copy of the POSIX test suite, so it may be that there is a hidden ongoing certification...

Comment: Also relevant is [the section on POSIX compliance](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX.html) in the GNU C library manual.

Comment: Linux is not an OS, just a kernel, so by itself it cannot be POSIX compliant. Inspur K-UX 3.0 is one example of  a Linux-based system that has been certified as compliant to UNIX 03.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  or Ubuntu, Debian. I am mainly interested in API, so does that mean Linux kernel suffices?

Comment: Aide-mémoire: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?diff=prev&oldid=711347640

Comment: Solaris is not compliant by default and cannot be made so because its POSIX `sh` (`/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`) has [dozens of non-compliances](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01603.html) (many of them major compared to those 32bit exit code in waitid which is a recent and unfortunate non-backward-compatible change to the standard). It still has been certified (11.4 to UNIX 07 recently) even though the OpenGroup knew plain well about those non-conformances.

Comment: @Tim, POSIX is an API specification. POSIX.1 covers the C API (libc and kernel mostly), POSIX.2 the shell and utilities API. On Debian/Ubuntu that involves kernel, the GNU libc, dash (or bash or mksh as Debian supports all 3 as sh), GNU coreutils, GNU sed, GNU awk or mawk, GNU cc, make... and many other utilities most of them from the GNU project. Note that Linux is not the only kernel supported by Debian.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: You seem to missnderstand a POSIX certification. If Martijn Dekker did make a bug report against the austin group standard, this would have resulted in an updated test suite. Getting the seal does not mean a platform is fully compliant but that it passed all tests. Any platform that got the seal needs to recheck the compliance once a year with the actual version of the test suite. The enhanced ksh88 from `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` is much closer to the POSIX standard than `ksh93` or `bash`  and it seems to be changed when non-compliances are detected.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas.  First of all POSIX.1 and former POSIX.2 are standards - not specifications. Nowadays  POSIX.1 covers more than just APIs as it documents a shell and several commands and utilities. This occured when XCU and POSIX.2 were folded into POSIX.1

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I forgot that `waitid()` exists since 1989 and is in the standard since 1995. So it is neither a recent addition, nor is there a need to be backward compatible, since the function is completely different - well it is nearly identical to the `cwait()` syscall that has been designed by former AT&T engineers in 1980 while they created the first UNIX clone `UNOS` for Charles River Data Systems.

Comment: It specifies the shell and utilities *API*. The conformance bugs of Solaris sh are bugs of that sh, not of the standard. The standard is fine in that regard. One can report a bug against the standard but not against the OpenGroup procedure for checking conformance other than by raising it on the ML like Martjin did. SUS changed from (sort-of) requiring the Linux behaviour for waitid() (that it be truncated to 8 bits) to the SysV behaviour in the 2016 edition IIRC. They did check with RedHat that the Linux folk would be OK with the change before doing so.

Comment: You are mistaken, I reported a bug against `waitid()` and the test scripts have been changed. SUS never required the Linux behavior but for some time introduced a wording in other parts of the standard that could be missunterpreted to apply for `waitid()` as well and not only to `wait()` and `waitpid()` as intended.

Comment: if Linux is not compliant then can you explain how [these 2 Linux distros are Unix-certified by the Open Group](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/): [Inspur's K-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspur_K-UX) and [Huawei's EulerOS](https://www.huawei.com/en/press-events/news/2016/9/huawei-kunlun-euleros-unix-certification)? [Is there a linux distro that's UNIX certified?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293396/44425)

Comment: I cannot see the huawai system, but Inspur seems to be certified against a very outdated POSIX version that did come with a broken certification test for `waitid()`. Unless the Linux kernel people change their mind and and fix their bugs in `waitid()` no Linux distro is POSIX compliant.

Comment: @schily both of them are certified with [UNIX 03 (i.e. SUS v3)](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/xy.htm), which is [equal to every other updated Unix OSes except Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Compliance) (the only Unix that is SUS v4 certified)

Comment: @phuclv: as mentioned: The UNIX-03 test suite has a buggy test for `waitid()` and it is pretty useless to claim that they passed the test when they cannot run software that was designed for a POSIX compliant `waitid()`. The only systems on your list that are POSIX compliant with respect to `waitid()`are from Oracle and SCO. The Apple system from that list neither returns the pid of the waited for process, nor the exit reason. I needed to write a real compliance test for my `configure` in order not to use `waitid()` on defective systems.

Comment: BTW: Solaris is the first platform that has been tested for Issue-7,TC2 and there are other systems (recent Apple systems) that have been tested for the first version of Issue-7 where the `waitid()` test at least check for 16 bits in the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is not XSI-compliant at all. For example, it does not provide the system header `<stdio.h>`. This is because Linux is only an operating system kernel. This kernel needs an additional userland implementation to be *able* to be XSI-compliant.

There are several Linux distributions that include the Linux kernel, an implementation of the C Standard Library, a shell, the various utilities and various other components.

All these parts together *may possibly* be XSI-compliant, but that needs to be tested and verified for each of these combinations.

Comment: You must be a mathematician, right? Saying Linux is only a kernel and as such can't fill the user space requirements is both entirely accurate and entirely useless in the context of the question asked. Note how they say "or Ubuntu, Debian in particular", a part you completely ignored. ([A comment from 2018 under the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467010/is-linux-considered-xsi-compliant-or-largely-so#comment850814_467012) also already mentions the "just a kernel" issue.)

Comment: I didn't completely ignore the Linux distributions. I said that _adding various parts to the kernel_ might result in an XSI-compliant system. I never tried to actually prove that myself, as it would take an enormous amount of time (or the appropriate test suite), both of which I am lacking.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the question and completely ignores details already mentioned that prevent any system using the "Linux kernel" from being XSI-compliant regardless if they have an otherwise XSI-complaint userland. Proper `waitid()` support, for example, is entirely a kernel issue and being pedantic about it properly being "GNU/Linux" or whatever doesn't help the reader at all.