# Why are most Linux distributions not POSIX-compliant?

Tags: linux, posix

Why are most Linux distributions not POSIX-compliant? I've seen in lots of places that they're not (e.g. [Mostly POSIX-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Mostly_POSIX-compliant)) but there's been no real explanation to back this up.

Is there something the C library and/or tools could do to get around this (i.e. no modifications to the kernel itself)? What needs to be done?

The supposed duplicate is asking which Linux distribution is POSIX-compliant; this is asking why most Linux distributions aren't POSIX-compliant. I'm asking for specific details (i.e. some function or command isn't compliant), not the reasons the specific distributions don't (try to) get certified.

This comment from @PhilipCouling (thanks!) explains it well:

> Compliance and certification are different subjects. The answers point to cost of (re)certification which is irrelevant to the subject of (non)compliance.

Comment: There is at least one Linux distribution which *is* POSIX compliant, [Inspur K-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspur_K-UX).

Comment: @Gilles This is not a duplicate; the supposed duplicate is asking which Linux distro is POSIX-compliant; this is asking why Linux isn't POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @JL2210, the second sentence of the duplicate is "What are the primary reasons that most distributions don't get certified?" and answers there address that.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm asking for specific details (i.e. some function or command isn't compliant), not the reasons they don't try to get certified.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Compliance and certification are different subjects.  The answers point to cost of (re)certification which is irrelevant to the subject of (non)compliance.

Comment: When compliance requires the existence of `/bin/cd`, which will not have any effect when called, one might question why any particular distribution will strive to meet compliance standards.

Comment: @doneal24 I don't recall that the exact path required is `/bin/cd`, but it's used to test if you can change directories into a path without actually changing directories. It's probably meant to be used in other tasks, like shell scripting and writing `Makefile`s.

Comment: I noticed a "too broad" close vote on this. Is there any way that I can make this less broad?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

POSIX does not specify a kernel interface, so Linux is largely irrelevant. It does specify the system interface, various tools, and extensions to the C standard, which could exist on top of any kernel. It is not POSIX-compliant in the sense that it's not mentioned, or it is POSIX-compliant in the sense that it's not mentioned, at your option.

[There are UNIX®-Certified Linux distributions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476945/73093), so it is certainly possible to have fully POSIX-compliant operating systems using Linux. [Huawei's EulerOS is one](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3622.htm) that has and that you can buy if you'd like. Most of the rest haven't paid their money and so don't have access to the [test suite](https://www.opengroup.org/testing/testsuites/vsx4.htm) to check conformance.

Whether they would satisfy it in practice is not clear, but some do try harder than others. I suspect that some of the BSDs are closer than most Linux distributions, but that's a guess: for example, I know that `execlp("cd", "/", NULL)` fails on most Linux distributions, but works on many BSDs and is required by POSIX.

Comment: Could someone easily get around this by just writing a `cd` program?

Comment: Sure, but it's unlikely that that's the *only* deviation, it's just an easy gratuitous compliance check I know off the top of my head. All of them are resolvable if someone made the effort.

Comment: Is there any unofficial test suite? I was sort of hoping to test my C library for conformance; the POSIX standard seems a bit ambiguous on a few functions.

Comment: Not that I know of, but maybe. At that level of specificity "unofficial" probably doesn't really cut it, though.

Comment: `cd` should be a binary in POSIX ..... quite impressive. Learnt somethng new everyday.

Comment: What would a cd program even do?  Change the directory and then exit?  What would be the point?