# What is the difference between UNIX and UNIX Like?

Tags: history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Linux a Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix)

I have heard Linux was not UNIX (I guess it still isn't) but that it was UNIX Like. Some people will just say "Linux is UNIX" or say "Linux, Solaris, something else and other UNIX-Like OSes".

Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: I *think* this is a duplicate, but if I'm not understanding you leave a comment