# Is Oracle Solaris UNIX?

Tags: solaris

Is Oracle Solaris officially declared UNIX?
I want to know all the official UNIX presently available in the market (whether free or paid).

Please correct me if I am wrong:
To the best of my knowledge, an operating system must satisfy all the terms and conditions as laid by the owners of "UNIX", The Open Group, to be coined as UNIX.
Linux is an UNIX-like kernel almost resembling UNIX but still open-source and free to distribute.

Comment: I'll never get used to ‘Oracle’ appearing in front of Solaris.

Answer (score 14):

You can find that information on The Open Group's website, namely in the [Register of Certified Products](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/) page.

Yes, Oracle Solaris is listed there.

You should check out this question: [Is Linux a Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix) for some interesting info on what UNIX & Unix are, and their relation to Linux and other systems.

Answer (score 3):

When Sun was an independent company, it [licensed System Vr4 Unix](http://www.anonymous-insider.net/unix/research/1994/0317.html) from Novell.  I know that Groklaw excoriated Sun for semi-playing-along with SCOG during the SCOG "IP" tempest, but Sun already had a license for Unix at the time.  So, Solaris is definitely Unix, in a licensing sense, as well as a certification sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,is UNIX,and is certified UNIX(like MacOS X,AIX,HP-UX and one linux distro for mainframes called Inspur K-UX).
Solaris is an historical unix,derived from SunOS and it take some things from Unix BSD,and many others from Unix SysV.
Unfortunately Oracle has decided to discontinue it(and Sparc architecture too).

Comment: That last sentence would warrant a link to a press release I think.

Comment: I'm not english and I speak/write a very bad english,sorry