# Is it possible to have bash but not awk?

Tags: bash, awk, posix, portability

Here on Stack Exchange we often see answers on [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) questions, that use tools other than the `bash` language, such as `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, etc.

These tools are specific in POSIX, so they should be available on most systems, but I was wondering if any systems exist where `bash` is available but not `awk`. Or does the availability of `bash` imply by necessity all POSIX tools?

Please consider all possible platforms, such as embedded systems, stripped down installations for working with old hardware, MS windows emulators, etc.

Comment: Are you asking for something more than https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82409/are-there-versions-of-unix-that-dont-have-awk-in-default-install?

Comment: In my experience, stripped-down systems are more likely to have awk than bash.  A shell like dash is much more appropriate for a stripped down system than the large and featureful bash.

Comment: @muru: Yes, that covers my question I think, should I flag it as a dupe, or just delete it?