# Need to execute javascript as a cron job... possible?

Tags: wget, headless

I need to load a page once per hour and execute the javascript on that page.  I currently load the page manually with Firefox, but I would like to automate this by running a cron job on the server, which is Ubuntu **Server** 8.04 LTS.

Some web searching suggests that the best thing would be to run `firefox -remote openurl(...)` and let gecko run the javascript, but this requires X11 which I don't know how to simulate on a server install.

So essentially I want an hourly job to run `firefox` in a simulated environment and discard the output.  (I'm not wed to `firefox`... I'd happily take a `wget`-like command that executes javascript.)

Comment: [Programmatic Python Browser with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1916711/168034)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a graphical browser (e.g. Firefox) that's displaying in a virtual X server (Xvfb). See [How can I run Firefox on Linux headlessly (i.e. without requiring libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-run-firefox-on-linux-headlessly-i-e-without-requiring-libgtk-x11-2-0), and perhaps also [How do I start Xvfb on startup on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/how-do-i-start-xvfb-on-startup-on-debian).

[Elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) is a text mode browser with optional Javascript support. The version in Ubuntu 8.04 is compiled without the JS support, so you'd have to compile your own and link it with the [Mozilla SpiderMonkey JavaScript library](http://www.mozilla.org/js/). [These instructions in the manual](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manual.html#ecmascript) may help.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add this to the mix, we ended up using [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) instead of the above.

Answer (score 2):

You could try http://www.phantomjs.org/ a headless WebKit browser.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Joby, but it looks like PhantomJS requires Xvfb anyway (ie, it's not really headless) so I'm probably just going to use Firefox (which I don't have to build myself).