# How do I run uTorrent?

Tags: utorrent

I just downloaded the uTorrent archive from their website and unpacked it. Inside were:

- docs
- utserver
- webui.zip

`utserver` is an executable, so I'm guessing that's what I'm supposed to run, but when I double-click it nothing happens. What should I do? I'm using Fedora 15

Comment: Can you try running it from a terminal? You might get some kind of useful error message that way

Comment: Given that utorrent is proprietary software, you might have better resulsts asking for support on their own forums.

Comment: Are you forced to use muTorrent? If not, use the (Transmission bittorrent client)[http://www.transmissionbt.com/]. It works!

Comment: I personally use deluge - I like its features and setup better than transmission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`utserver` is a command line program. (You can tell — well, with enough technical knowledge you can — by opening a terminal, changing to the right directory and running `ldd ./utserver`: this doesn't list any GUI library). You just need to start it, and after that you interact through the provided web UI: point your browser to `http://localhost:8080/gui/` (or whatever `ut_webui_port` is set to in the configuration file). You'll have to install the GUI as well (it's in the zip file), this isn't documented.

Comment: okey, what do I need to to make it run always and also (if possible) not when im logged in?

Comment: @Jason94: Add a `@reboot /path/to/utserver >~/.utserver.log 2>&1` line to your crontab; see [Bash Script on Startup? (Linux)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/bash-script-on-startup-linux).

Comment: crontab is good for always running even after restart right? This is good to know. I was just using `screen ./utserver` which makes utserver run as a background process and returns the shell prompt so you can do other stuff. For WebUI I use: http://localhost:8080/gui/web/index.html - Make sure you at least change the default password to something else under settings.

Comment: @Sun A `@reboot` entry in crontab runs a program each time the system starts.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see at uTorrent's web site, what they offer for Linux is a server and a web interface, so when you launch utorrent, it forks to background and listens on some port (see documentation) so you can access it with your browser (again, see documentation for the exact address or port, it's most likely 127.0.0.1:some_port).

Some *windows* versions of uTorrent are [reported](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6824) to work fine with [wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), so you might try them and have a normal desktop application with tray icon and such.

You can also check Linux bittorent clients - transmission, deluge or ktorrnet - chances are they would suit you.

// I cannot add a comment, but what exactly are you trying to do? Running Linux on your desktop is one thing, building a headless torrent/multimedia/ftp server is slghtly different

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent Server only supports 32 Bit Architecture. It will run on 64 Bit Architecture however you need to install 32 Bit Support.

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely do NOT RECOMMEND running uTorrent in linux, you have so much better applications like Ktorrent, Transmisson, Azureus, etc.
But if you want to insist in running utorrent, you need decompress the utorrent tarball, then run a terminal, 'cd' into the utorrent directory, and in terminal type:

./utserver

than run a browser, for example firefox and enter this url "http://localhost:8080/gui/"  than it will prompt a dialog asking user and password, in the user field enter:

admin

and it will show you utorrent UI

PS: serious, theres much better alternatives in linux.

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything to the accepted answer...