# Why Unix is sometimes referred as UN*X or *nix?

Tags: history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a * When There is Mention of Unix Throughout the Internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/why-is-there-a-when-there-is-mention-of-unix-throughout-the-internet)

Why Unix is sometimes referred as UN*X or *nix? Asterisk usually means that some letters are skipped but I can't form any words. And it seems to me that would better be *n*x and then you could make Linux at least.

Comment: Linux is not UNIX and UNIX is not Linux. The UNIX kernel was written in the seventies, the Linux kernel was written in 1991. Linux is very much UNIX-like, but they are still different and should be reffered to different.

Comment: @hesse while technically accurate, people still do it, and theres no getting around it. The question still stands.

Comment: I believe 'Unix' is/was a trademark.  Also, there are quite a number of Unix-like operating systems out there: Linux, Aix, HP-UX &c, so it's handy to have a term to refer to them all.