# How is "fifty million man-years" development effort inside <The Art of Unix Programming>

Tags: books

I was reading the book <[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/preface.html)>

There is one line claiming

> The three and a half decades between 1969 and 2003 is a long time. Going by the historical trend curve in number of Unix sites during that period, probably somewhere upwards of fifty million man-years have been plowed into Unix development worldwide.

That's `(50million man-year / 35 year) = (1.47 million man-year / year)`  goes into Unix development during that period. It means 1.47 million developers worked on Unix system yearly.

Personally I find the number a bit hard to believe. Or am I understanding the number in the wrong way?

Comment: Your concern seems valid.

Comment: Where is the 1.47 million number coming from? Your quote mentions 50, not 1.47. Also, I suspect this means "people developing on Unix" rather than "people involved in developing Unix itself". Given that the vast majority of servers in the world run some sort of *nix, I wouldn't be too surprised if there are indeed many millions of programmers who have worked in *nix environments in those 35 years.

Comment: @terdon Updated the question according to the comment.

Comment: @terdon 
If the `Unix development` is interpreted in the way of `engineers write code goes into *nix code base` + `engineers write code on top of *nix`, then the number seems like reasonable.
Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I used Unix/Linux for most of a 50 year career. When I found a bug, I generated a fix and sent it in. Twice. How much of my 50 years is counted as "development effort"? 98% of all free floating statistics are made up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "man-year per year" -- just like "kilowatts-hour per hour", it's nonsense.

But that's probably the point of your question.

Anyways, that guy was a bit exagerating by assuming that everybody *using* Unix was actually *contributing* to its development. That's a bit like summing up great the contribution of [rat labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_to_the_laboratory_mouse#/media/File:Monument_to_lab_mouse-1.JPG) as so many "millions of lives *dedicated to science*"; correct, but not exactly what one could assume from the title.

Comment: Updated the question according to the comment `There's no such thing as "man-year per year" `.

Comment: You are reading it wrong .The book and the quote talk about *"people using Unix as a development platform"* not how many that had worked on developing the core Unix system. It is about Unix development culture, philosophy and design.

Answer (score 2):

The quote is a footnote from in the preface of the book. More concrete in this excerpt:

> […] the Unix culture has an unwritten engineering tradition that has developed over literally millions of man-years<sup>[1]</sup> of skilled effort. This book is written in the belief that understanding that tradition, and adding its design patterns to your toolkit, will help you become a better programmer and designer.
> <sup>[1]</sup> *The three and a half decades between 1969 and 2003 is a long time. Going by the historical trend curve in number of Unix sites during that period, probably somewhere upwards of fifty million man-years have been plowed into Unix development worldwide.*

From question:

> It means 1.47 million developers worked on Unix system yearly.

That depends on how one interpret *"worked on"* as well as what is meant by Unix. It is *not* about developing the Unix systems themselves, though of course these are also included. It is about using Unix as a platform for development. It being universities, companies, timeshares, servers, devices, personal and so on where *nix<sup>[2]</sup> is and has been used.

More widely the book is about the Unix(-like) development culture, philosophy and design.

<sup>[2] I use *nix here as the author talks about systems far beyond proprietary UNIX in the book. For example: *"[the rise of Linux and other open-source Unixes (such as the modern BSD variants).](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s03.html)"* 
Also see [Is Linux a Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4097/140633), which also links to [Why is there a * When There is Mention of Unix Throughout the Internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2356/140633)</sup>